# const name as a part of a other const in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, constants

Say you got a const:

```js
const const1 = 'hello, "cheese"'
```

Is it then possible to name another const with the "hello" part of `const1`?

I tried this but it failed:

```js
const const1.split(', ')[0] = const1.split(', ')[1]
```

So could someone give me a answer if this is even possible to do?

Comment: You want a dynamic variable name? Why?

Comment: once you split it, yes can do using `eval` but it's not recommended. better use it like a dynamic property instead: `obj[const1.split(', ')[0]] = 'something'`

Answer (score 2):

You can't reassign a const, and you can't have an expression as the left hand side of a declaration. Use `let` and don't redeclare the variable.

```js
let str1 = "foo, bar"
str1.split(`, `)[0] = str1.split(`, `)[1]
```

If your goal is to dynamically declare (name) a variable, you could use an object with a computed key, as in `{ [someVariable]: somethingElse }`, for example `{ [str1.split(", ")[0]]: str1.split(", ")[1] }`